# Comparing dates in JSTL

Tags: java, jstl

I'm a front end programmer that's new to JSTL coding and trying to find out if one date happens before the other.

```
<fmt:parseDate var="convertedDate" value="${checkDate}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" parseLocale="en_US"/>
<c:set var="year2020" value="${<%=new Date("1-1-2019") %>}"
<c:set var="is2019CheckDate" value="${convertedDate < year2020}" />
```

But this is complaining:

```
"${<%=new Date("1-2-2019") %>}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${<%=new Date("1-2-2019") %>}]
```

How can I express the new date in JSTL? Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: Why do you believe that the [`java.util.Date(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-java.lang.String-) constructor can parse the text `1-1-2019`? Did you read the documentation of that constructor, or more precisely the javadoc of the [`parse(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse-java.lang.String-) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I express the new date in JSTL?

Same way you parsed the `checkDate` string:

```jsp
<fmt:parseDate var="year2020" value="1/1/2019" pattern="M/d/yyyy"/>
```

Though I don't know why the year 2020 starts at the *beginning* of 2019.